# Use a filter in an outer join in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following entities:

```
public class Company
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

public class CompanyCurrency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get the list of currencies for a country. If a country does not have an entry for a currency I need a line for that missing entry too.

The statement I have right now is:

```
var  currencies  = 
from c in Currencies
join cc in CompanyCurrency 
on  c.ID equals cc.CurrencyId 
into jointable
from resultiten in  jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()


select new {c.Name  ,
HasEntry =  resultiten == null ? 0:1,  
rate =  resultiten != null ? resultiten.Rate:0 ,
}  ;
```

This is not filtered by a countryID . I tried to add a filter by

```
from c in Currencies
join cc in CompanyCurrency 
on  c.ID equals cc.CurrencyId 
into jointable
from resultiten in  jointable.DefaultIfEmpty()
where resultiten.CompanyId == 1 || resultiten == null


select new {c.Name  ,
HasEntry =  resultiten == null ? 0:1,  
rate =  resultiten != null ? resultiten.Rate:0
```

But that does not have a result for a currency that has en entry for a company other then companyID 1.

The cooresponding SQL query would be

```
select  * 
from [dbo].[Currency] c
left outer join [dbo].[CompanyCurrency] cc
on c.id = cc.Currencyid
and cc.[Companyid] = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either apply the filter **before** the `join`:

```
join cc in CompanyCurrency.Where(e => e.CompanyId == 1)
```

or as part of the join

```
on new { CurrencyId = c.ID, CompanyId = 1 } equals new { cc.CurrencyId, cc.CompanyId }
```

For `inner join`s it doesn't really matter, but for `outer join` it's important (the same btw applies to SQL queries).

Comment: Thnx, both queries work for me. I guess the first one is easier to read.